# How to sort names in list by the first character of the name

Tags: list, sorting, for-loop, while-loop, count

I need to loop through a list an count the number of names that begin with each letter of the alphabet. How can I do this? Below is the beginning of my code.

```
File = open("yob2016",'r')
name = []
gender = []
count = []
for line in File:
    value = line.split(",")
    name.append(value[0])
    gender.append(value[1])
    count.append(float(value[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
d = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
for name in names:
    letter = name[0].lower()
    d[letter] += 1
```

This will give you a dictionary with each alphabet as key and number of names that begin with this alphabet as value.